# Data Validation not working in Edit Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite

I want to implement validation on text box for whether the name exists in the database. I am using wpf with c#. I have implemented a validation on the text box while saving new data. My problem is in Edit Mode: when I go to edit mode and try to save, an error appears that the name already exist.

The Below Code works fine on save mode But when it comes to Edit mode when datas get binding the error message shows.

pls suggest me a good way to implement the validation that work on edit mode too.

```
class MyParent
 {
   public MyCarClass CurrentCarEntity {get; set;}

    private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {            
         CurrentCarEntity.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
         var getName = //Code for getting name from local db

         if(CurrentCarEntity.Name != Null)
           {
              if(getName.Equals(CurrentCarEntity.Name))
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Name Already Exists");
                }
           }
     }   
}
```

Comment: You say you have implemented validation on your textbox, but I don't see it anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are following the wrong approach

let us assume we have a class called users like following

```
public class User: IValidatableObject
{
     public int Id{get; set;}
     public string UserName{get; set;}
     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
          if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
               yield return new ValidationResult("Username field is required!", new string[]{"UserName"});
          else 
          {
               // check if another User has the same username already
               var db= new YourDbContext();
               var exists=db.Users.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id!=Id && t.UserName.ToLower()=UserName.ToLower());
               if(exists!=null)
                   yield return new ValidationResult("Username is already used by another user!", new string[]{"UserName"});
          }
     }
}
```

you don't need to worry about the edit or create, since in both cases you are checking the database if the Users table contains another user,and not same user you are creating or editing, has the same username.

hope this will help you

Comment: I am using Entity framework to get data from db(SQLITE), please tellme how to implement IDataErrorInfo or IValidatableObject for my scenario. @hadi

Comment: @RanjithM i edited the code and added the IValidatableObject implementation

Comment: @RanjithM you mentioned above in your question tags that you are using WPF, i didn't use WPF before, but if it's same as windows form applications, then you need to implement the DataErrorInfo class that implements IDataErrorInfo and IValidatableObject, both can work together, and i can show you how if you still need any help

Comment: have a look on this post, it might help you, http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/10/16/validator.aspx

Comment: thanks for the replies dudes, let me give a try and will let u know the status... @HadiHassan mah

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're making validation fail for the entire form if the name already exists - validation will trigger every time you try to submit (edit, insert, etc) so edits will always fail.

I would make two textboxes, one for inserts and one for edits. Hide the insert box while in edit mode, or if you want to stick with one, at least disable the validator when editing.

Comment: If i disable validation in Edit Mode the name may be get duplicate if the user enters an existing name... is there any other way to do this???